# Visual Studio 2013 MySQL module installation fails

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, visual-studio-2013

When I'm trying to install the Node.JS MySQL module trough Visual Studio 2013 npm Package Management, the installation fails due to the following errors:

```
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token
```

How do I solve this or is there another way to do this?

Comment: In Visual Studio’s “npm Package Management” dialog, are you installing this from the “Specify Package Details” tab, or from the “Search npm Repository” tab?

Comment: I was trying to install the packages globally, because locally the installation failed every single time. Although I've manage to solve my problem. See the answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem. The only thing I needed to do was New Project > Blank Express Application (instead of Blank Node.js console/web application). Then, in Solution Explorer, right click on npm > Manage npm Modules > search and install locally the required package.